# flutter debugging with pixel 8 start to show E/lutter_progetto( 5180): PIXEL: ioctl err: 1

Tags: flutter, flutter-debug

I'm developing an application with flutter and today suddenly when I carry out my debugging tests with a physical device (pixel 8) I receive the following error in the console at every interaction.

I didn't find anything similar doing some research, it started appearing suddenly and I don't know the reason nor can I hypothesize what the cause is. Every application I launch on this pixel 8 has this problem. I have a second device, nothing phone 1, and this doesn't happen.

Furthermore, when starting each application, these strings appear (the yellow one are more than one line) that I had never seen before (always and only on pixel 8).

I would like to understand what happened, can anyone help me?

I tried cleaning the flutter folder with flutter clean,  without getting any results. I restarted the pixel 8, without getting any results.

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you ever manage to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, neither found the cause.